# Error: File not found with singular glob: (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)

Tags: gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulpfile

I am trying to automate a task with watch, in gulp. I am a beginner at this.

This is code:

```
const { series, src, dest, watch } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Función que compila SASS

function css( ) {
    return src('src/scss/app.scss')
        .pipe( sass())
        .pipe( dest('./build/css') )
}

function minificarcss() {
    return src('src/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe( sass ({
        outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }))
    .pipe( dest('./build/css') )
}

function watchArchivos() {
    watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', css ); // * = La carpeta actual - ** = Todos los archivos con esa extensión
}

exports.css = css;
exports.minificarcss = minificarcss;
exports.watchArchivos = watchArchivos;
```

This is the error, I have no idea why it happens, all files are well written.

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\FestivalMusica_inicio> gulp watchArchivos
[07:47:10] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\FestivalMusica_inicio\gulpfile.js
[07:47:10] Starting 'watchArchivos'...
[07:47:41] Starting 'css'...
[07:47:41] 'css' errored after 19 ms
[07:47:41] Error: File not found with singular glob: C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/FestivalMusica_inicio/src/scss/app.scss (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
```

The path of the directories is well written:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that the file: 'C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/FestivalMusica_inicio/src/scss/app.scss' is written correctly. Sometimes we forget something. This problem, that's it, the file does not exist.